# How to change chromosome names in hundreds of genomes?

Tags: python, sed, sh, rename

I have one hundred of genomes with .bed files. I want to change the chromosome name (appears in the first column)for each genome with Species_ID (3 characters) plus sequential numbers for MscanX program for comparison of syntenic regions.

The current bed files have a variety of formats... And the chromosome numbers also varies.

For example,

`CP006020.1 or gi|1002316256|dbj|BCGA01000001.1| or Scaffold_1`

Any idea how to change all of them automatically instead one by one?

Li
Thanks

---

**Edit:** Sorry for forgetting upload the files. For example my input is

```
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g2.t1  4928    6961
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g3.t1  9344    9862
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g4.t1  10744   13401
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g5.t1  16466   16807
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g6.t1  18381   21437
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g7.t1  21754   22092
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g8.t1  22562   23695
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g9.t1  24921   28616
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g10.t1 28815   32498
```

or

```
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g1.t1 3762    4427
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g2.t1 5216    5500
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g3.t1 10276   12591
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g4.t1 12621   13423
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g5.t1 23064   23738
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g6.t1 26600   27292
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g7.t1 27601   28044
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g8.t1 33199   33741
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g9.t1 33912   34990
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g10.t1    41641   44574
```

I only want to change the chromosome name in the first column. Change the orginal one to Chr1, Chr2 to Chr... depends on how many scaffolds are in the file.

Comment: We will need some more information. What are .bed files? What different formats are there? From the tags it looks like you know that python or sed will be involved. It's probably a different invocation of sed for each .bed file format. Try posting a few lines from one of the files, and how you want those lines to look after you're done.

Comment: @Yuanning,  Add some data of input file and expected outcome.

Comment: The additional information is _still_ not sufficient for a non-geneticist to understand your question. Please give an expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for forgetting upload the files. For example my input is

```
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g2.t1  4928    6961
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g3.t1  9344    9862
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g4.t1  10744   13401
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g5.t1  16466   16807
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g6.t1  18381   21437
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g7.t1  21754   22092
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g8.t1  22562   23695
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g9.t1  24921   28616
CP006020.1  Ashbya_aceri.g10.t1 28815   32498
```

or

```
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g1.t1 3762    4427
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g2.t1 5216    5500
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g3.t1 10276   12591
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g4.t1 12621   13423
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g5.t1 23064   23738
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g6.t1 26600   27292
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g7.t1 27601   28044
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g8.t1 33199   33741
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g9.t1 33912   34990
gi|1002316735|dbj|BCKQ01000001.1|   Ascoidea_asiatica.g10.t1    41641   44574
```

I only want to change the chromosome name in the first column. Change the orginal one to Chr1, Chr2 to Chr... depends on how many scaffolds are in the file.

Comment: Thank you for posting your inputs, but still unclear. Can you provide the expected output based on the input above?  Then we will be able to help you solve the problem. BTW please post your update of question by appending to the original post, not as an answer. BR.

Comment: I have edited your question; you should have been able to do this yourself. Please delete this "answer". (Especially before it gets down-voted!)